# Bluetooth GUID in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, guid

I use C#.Net (feet32 lib) to build a bluetooth server/client tool. I follow the instruction from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xxnpq6ePQMk, but I met a problem of Guid. After I input the Bluetooth Guid that accessed from my laptop ( Device manager -> double click your bluetooth device to open it's properties -> details -> Class Guid), it still cannot connect. I am not sure the method I obtain GUID is correct, or other problems ? Thanks!

```
Guid mUUID = new Guid("e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974");
// Guid mUUID = new Guid("be5ef05c-288d-45d7-b786-eb8e0b0d67cc");
bool serverStarted = false;

public void ServerConnectThread()
{
    serverStarted = true;
    updateUI("server started, wait for client");
    BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
    blueListener.Start();
    BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
    updateUI("Client has connected");
    Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
    while (true)
    {
        //handle server connection
        byte[] received = new byte[1024];
        mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
        updateUI("Received:" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct GUID is not class guid but rather its bluetooth service GUID and you would see it from the same list you saw the class GUID . Class GUID and bluetooth service GUID are different.

Comment: Thank you! I went through the list saw the class GUID. However, I did not find the item "bluetooth service GUID", if possible, could you tell me the name of item "bluetooth service GUID" in the list?

Comment: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB   but this guid is for serial port devices.I  Dont know what kind of device you are using.

Comment: This id cannot work on my laptop, my device is a HP elitebook Folio 1040. The bluetooth is Intel Wireless Bluetooth 7265. Thanks

Comment: As you mentioned, I've tried 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, but it not works, I do not know where I could find the correct bluetooth GUID in my windows system?

Comment: Ok. To do bluetooth connection you need 2 devices. What is the other device you are trying to connect to?. The Guid does not seem to be the problem. Guid is just used as an identifier for the device. You can create your own Guid by going to visual Studio > Tools > create guid. But make sure you use thesame guid for both device. And also connection to a bluetooth device should be based on name and not guid. So try reading the documentation of the library and know how to connect proper

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid mUUID = BluetoothService.SerialPort;
```

Try this instead